# Why was this specific question placed on hold by a moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

When asking [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209259/javascript-with-checkbox) a moderator decided to place it on hold as unclear. However, another user has given an answer as a comment.

Why was it necessary to place this question on hold, especially given that the comment did solve my issue?

Comment: It's on hold because the moderator felt the question was unclear.  Clarify the question so that it *is* clear and it can be reopened.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - That wording was mine, note the qualification of essentially. Sure, only 2 instead of 5. Please edit that line to be more descriptive of the scenario if you wish.

Comment: The question was flagged as low quality, I agreed. TBH, I read the question, thought it was terrible, and closed it.  If you can edit it into something better and somewhat understandable, it could be reopened.

Comment: @TravisJ ah, OK; I just removed *"unilaterally"*, thanks!

Comment: @bluefeet - No offense, but you kind of set a bad standard here. *This* was a question you felt was low quality, and had absolutely no chance of redemption? I looked at your tags, and you have never answered a single javascript nor jquery question. It is fairly obvious that the checked property of an input element will not show up as an attribute, as it is a property and jQuery is fairly explicit about that. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/f2228d8o/ . So the checkbox element and the use of attr was really all that was required.The only issue was the poor use of grammar and fairly common problem.

Comment: @TravisJ *"had absolutely no chance of redemption?"* - they didn't **delete** it, they put it **on hold**. We *hope* that users will improve their questions such that they can be reopened and answered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Very low quality flags are only for content with no chance of redemption. "I agreed with the very low quality flag" is what that was in response to.

Comment: @TravisJ I closed it, I didn't delete it to give the OP the chance to redeem it. I don't need to be an expert in a tag to judge the quality of it.  My options when handling a VLQ flag on a question are to 1) decline the flag and then vote the question or 2) close the question which marks the flag as helpful.  One step or two, most mods will select the single process.

Comment: @bluefeet - You should have let the community close it if that was what was going to happen. You closed it as unclear, but it was very easily answerable. If anything it was a duplicate. It seems that it was only unclear to you because of a lack of expertise in this instance. While I understand that you generally take proper action, I do not believe you got this one correct. It was an excessive closure with an improper reason.

Comment: @bluefeet - In my experience most mods would decline the VLQ flag on a question like this. It is not worth mod time to review questions for closure, and that guidance has been rather direct with regards to flagging questions as very low quality. If a user wants to flag a question for closure, they should select a close reason.

Comment: @TravisJ Unfortunately VLQ flags on questions linger in the VLQ flag queue for a long time that's part of the problem with these flags on questions, they stick around in the queue not getting handled by anyone. So I made an attempt to clear the queue this morning. As I said I don't need to be an expert in a tag to judge the quality of a question.

Comment: You forced me to del it. I now it know, but this question would be h elpful for others, I think. Of course it was not such a highly sophisticated question as others, but I spent 2 hrs to find this.

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair *"You froced me to del it"* - nobody forced you to delete it. *"this question would be h elpful for others"* - your first comment identified an existing answer, why is this information needed twice?

Comment: @bluefeet - So here is where I am confused. And as a moderator, I feel like you have a large soap box both in your actions and comments. If I find questions that I *know* will go bad, should I flag them as VLQ in the future? I have tried this in the past, and they have been declined, rather consistently, and even with specific response. Do you advocate flagging questions which users feel will be closed as VLQ?

Comment: @Walter The way the question was phrased it was very hard to make heads or tails of the problem you encountered. It would have been very hard for any future visitor to find because of that vagueness, so it would hardly have been very useful. That's also exactly the reason why it got put on hold in the first place.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my second comment was to just say it once more, that on some sites this is still wrong. (see embaracado). In futur I will not say something twice. OK?

Comment: @deceze ok As english is not my mothertongue I will try to formulate future questions clearer. BTW was this the reason why I can  not ask any question on the forum? How long must I wait? Can you explain me the further process?

Comment: @TravisJ No, I'm not an advocate of using VLQ on questions that should be closed, that's what close votes/flags are for. I dislike VLQ flags on questions, I think it is just plain pointless when we have a process to close questions and many times I will decline those flags. However, if I have a VLQ flag on a question that I also believe should be closed, it is far easier for me to perform a single action of closure than performing 2 actions (decline the VLQ and close the question).

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair if you're now rate-limited, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Comment: @bluefeet - Thanks for the explanations :)

Comment: @Walter English wasn't so much a problem I think rather than simply not expressing the problem well. The way you wrote the question one must 1) read the entire question, 2) read the "error message" you mention, 3) read the code again to see where that message stems from, 4) trace back in the code to what caused this message, 5) finally understand the core issue you're asking about. That core issue could have been expressed much more straight forward, starting with the question title.

Comment: @deceze Ok, I will imporve and learn. In futrue I will try to write clear questions. Promised.

Comment: @deceze I know I can not ask for unban me. But I have already modified and deleted my low-quality questions. Why I am still banned to ask questions from my account?

Comment: Can't tell you anything other than http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/476

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I have read it, but I have only now two downrated questions with -2 reps. I really do not know which question I still have to fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There were multiple problems with your question.

- There were multiple potential bugs *in your code*.
- You described the behavior you disliked, but didn't describe the behavior you *expected*. In particular, you didn't actually lay out the scenario in which you were testing (is the code run only on startup? What is the markup it references? What value were you expecting?)
- Your title doesn't actually describe the problem you're facing either.

The close reason links to this page: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you should read that, and also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). They'll help you to write better questions in the future.